# What's the difference between position and positionInPixels

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In the past I always see that the property called `position` and `positionInPixels` are the same. This time `position * 2 == positionInPixels`. Who can tell me what's the difference between these 2 properties or when their value will be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`position` is in points and `positionInPixels` is in pixels. On non-retina device 1 point = 1 pixel. On retina device like iPhone 4/4S and the New iPad, 1 point = 2 pixels.

Per [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Characteristics/Characteristics.html):

> Note: **Pixel** is the appropriate unit of measurement to use when discussing the size of a device screen or the size of an icon you create in an image-editing application. **Point** is the appropriate unit of measurement to use when discussing the size of an area that is drawn onscreen.
>
> **On a standard-resolution device screen, one point equals one pixel, but other resolutions might dictate a different relationship. On a Retina display, for example, one point equals two pixels.**
>
> See ["Points Versus Pixels"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW15) in [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503) for iOS for a complete discussion of this concept.

Answer (score 0):

`position` gives you a position in points, whereas `positionInPixels` gives you the position in pixels. On an iPhone 4, e.g., position can range from (0,0) to (320, 480) (in portrait mode); positionInPixels can range from (0,0) to (640, 960) to reflect the higher resolution its retina display.

Basically, they are different on retina display devices; they are the same on non retina display devices.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

When you use Retina display your canvas still consists of 320x480 points but each point is composed of 2 pixels. In the standard display each point is one pixel. This is why retina display is more detailed as more pixel data can be used in textures. So position in pixels refers to the position on a specific pixel. (i.e. point 0 can be pixel 0 or pixel 1 in high retina display)